# bpftrace uretprobe go reader pattern print buffer

Tags: bpftrace

I am looking for a bpftrace example for the reader pattern in go - a function that takes a buffer as input, fills that buffer and returns the written bytes and a potential error.
Something like:
`# bpftrace -p <pid> -e 'uprobe:main:crypto/tls.Conn.Read { $ptr = arg0 }, uretprobe:main:crypto/tls.Conn.Read { printf("%s", str($ptr, retval0)) }'`

---

Found [this project](https://github.com/mechpen/gotlsdump/tree/master) which solves the problem using bcc.
Also stumbled across the discussions around ebpf and dynamic stacks in golang [on github/golang](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22008) and [on github/iovisor](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/issues/1320#issuecomment-407927542).
This does not answer the question (in the context of bpftrace) but it seems that there is a bigger problem which needs to be fixed before further investigating on this.